# How to import projects properly using Git from cloud

Tags: eclipse, git, import, repository, bitbucket

How to properly import projects from BitBucket or another cloud repository? I have Eclipse Neon JavaEE. Even if there is Git preinstalled yet and (for my purposes important) Maven too. The imported projects are not real projects.

The straighforward way is:

1. File -> Import -> Git -> Clone URI (copied from repository i.e.
   BitBucket)
2. Fill in username/password if needed
3. Next

Now I can see this picture (Ubuntu Linux 16.04)
[image: Unuseful options for cloning]

But no any from this options clone huge of projects properly.
To successful clone projects I must in this moment

4. Cancel process (cloning is in local repository yet)
5. and manually add projects one after another one into workspace  in Git Perspective on expanded Working tree using
6. Right click on projects -> Import Projects...

Do you know anybody how do this operation better?
Next another thing is, that I cannot select more projects, because the option Import Projects... will disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to:

- clone those repositories manually in command-line (with a Git you install yourself, separately from the one used by Eclipse).
  Clone those repo in any path you want, *outside* of the Eclipse workspace folder.
- import the project you want into the Eclipse workspace, by using the local path where the Git repo has just been cloned.
- once imported, select the Team/share option by right-clicking on the imported project in Eclipse: it should recognized the project is *already* shared as a Git repo.

That wy, you don't try to do everything with Eclipse in one Go: you separate and keep better control on each step (clone, import, share)

Comment: Yes. Somebody notified me, that in Eclipse in Git not going everything smoothly. Another way is to Open Git perspective, clone repository from there and next steps (5,6) are again the same as in my question.